# Composing Interfaces in C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I wish to write a C++ function that takes as its argument an object that conforms to two unrelated interfaces. There are several ways this might be done; I list three below along with my critiques. (Please bear with me until I get to the actual question).

1) As a template function

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T& x) {
    x.fromInterfaceA();
    x.fromInterfaceB();
}
```

This is perhaps the best of the 'standard' solutions, but ensuring that `x` really inherits from `A` and `B` requires additional `static_assert`s, `type_traits`, etc., which is clumsy and long-winded. Also, the user is forced to constantly write template code where in fact there is no really generic behavior desired.

2) By having the function accept a specific derived class

```
struct A {
    // ...
    virtual void fromInterfaceA() = 0;
};

struct B {
    // ...
    virtual void fromInterfaceB() = 0;
};

struct AB : public A, public B {};

void foo(const AB& ab) {}
```

We are forced to create a new class just to express the composition of two other classes, and, even worse, `foo()` is not able to accept arguments that might inherit from `A` and `B` via a different route, e.g. through an intermediate class. We could quickly have a taxonomic nightmare, where there are multiple micro-interfaces.

3) By having `foo` accept a separate argument for each type, and passing the object multiple times.

```
void foo(const A& xAsA, const B& xAsB) {}
int main() {AB ab; foo(ab, ab);}
```

This is the most flexible solution (since it would also fit well with a composition-over-inheritance approach), yet it is also confusing, obscures the fact that `foo` is supposed to operate on a single object, and allows `foo` to accept two separate objects, possibly leading to pathological behavior.

In Haskell, we can compose type constraints in the way I'm talking about. It would be nice if syntax existed in C++ that allowed the same thing; I can see, though, that this would have serious implications for the internals of the class mechanism. We could write a template class, something like this rough sketch:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class Composition
{
    public:

        template<typename T> Composition(T& t) : t1_(t), t2_(t) {}

        operator T1&() {return t1_;}
        operator T2&() {return t2_;}
        template<typename T> T& as() {return operator T&();}

    private:

        T1& t1_;
        T2& t2_;
};
```

which appears to offer the advantages of the template solution, (1), while quarantining the actual template code.

My question is: are there any standard design patterns that deal with this issue? Or, alternatively, is there a paradigm where the problem goes away, while still allowing the same kind of flexibility I'm talking about? I'm also interested in more general critiques or thoughts on the discussion above.

Comment: Another option is to have `A` and `B` derive from an empty `Base` class with virtual destructor. Then you can use dynamic casts to `A` and `B`. (Not that I think its any cleaner than the options you outline.)

Comment: Agree on both counts - and it all depends on the problem at hand.  I think I was implicitly thinking about (1) being able to compose *any* classes and (2) having compile time time checks.

Comment: Can you split it into 2 functions? How does the function use both A and B together? Regarding 3, you could assert they are the same object.

Comment: @NeilKirk Splitting did occur as a possible design principle. However, I just think it's reasonable to be able to specify the type of an object as conforming to two or more interfaces without getting tied up in complex class hierarchies etc. I suppose you could think of something like a mathematical function, where we're using two properties of the operand, like the fact that it has both an additive and multiplicative inverse.

Comment: I get the impression you'd be interested in the C++ Concepts Lite proposals, which are as close as C++ is likely to come in the next half dozen years to formalising type constraints similar to Haskell's.  Lots about that epic effort via Google....

Comment: @TonyD Cheers - I had a brief look at the intro on isocpp.org, and it looks like a really nice improvement - the improvement in compiler error messages related to templates would by itself be a huge help. Incidentally, another extension I would really like to see in C++ is 'modules', but it doesn't sound like that will be happening any time soon...

Comment: There're [proposals for that](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4047.pdf) too....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example it is sufficient to just convert the argument as the two types.

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T& x) {
    const A* asA = &x;
    const B* asB = &x;
    // .. now use them ..
}
```

This will give a compile error if T is not derived from both A and B. No need for traits or compile time asserts.

One interesting advantage of doing it this way is that it scales nicely to 3 or more types. (Though needing this is probably a sign of something going icky in your design).

If you really want more customizability of the algorithm I'd consider

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T& x) {
  const A* asA = FooTraits<T>::asA(x);
  const B* asB = FooTraits<T>::asB(x);
  ...
}
```

with a default of

```
template<typename T> class FooTraits<T> {
public:
   static const A* asA(const T& x) { return &x; }
   static const B* asB(const T& x) { return &x; }
}
```

which will then allow you to use composition instead of inheritance for some of your types later.

Also now having this apply for more than three types doesn't feel as hacky to me.. since composition or delegation etc is possible.

Comment: Good point! It probably makes the 'template' solution somewhat better, but in my mind does not fully clear up the issue... One other thing that I didn't say is that we often may not even wish to enforce that `x` inherits from `A` and `B` -- templates' 'duck typing' behavior.

Comment: ... and I just also read the edit to your answer, the bit involving `FooTraits`. A really good point in that the flexibility to use composed classes adds genuine value. It also makes the template solution a true generic solution rather than a use of templates to deal with what some people might view as a deficiency of the language.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, as it makes it clear how using a template solution allows us to program in a more general way: we can accept classes that can *convert* to `A` and `B`, as opposed to inheriting from them.

Comment: IMHO, worth noting that the template - having extracted `asA` and `asB` - can still call a non-templated function `foo(const A&, const B&)` if it's desirable to keep the implementation out of line or avoid possible bloat when there are lots of `T` types... i.e. it can be a convenience wrapper in the public API.